# Applying functions to vector elements to make rows in a new dataframe

Tags: r

I've got an interesting problem and have no idea where to begin -- in fact, I wasn't even sure how to title the question!  What I want to do is apply functions to elements of a dataframe and use these to make new rows in a new dataframe.  For example, suppose we have a dataframe `df1` that gives some `X` and `Y` data for various `State`s:

```
df1 <- data.frame(State=c("AL","AK"), X=c(1,3), y=c(2,4))
```

What I would like to do is start with the first state `AL`, and make a new dataframe `df2`with 3 rows, where the new values of `df2$X` are calculated using 3 different functions to give, for example: `df1$X`, `df1$X - 1`, and `df1$X + 1`.  Likewise, I want to do a similar thing for new values of `df2$Y`, which in this example are calculated as `df1$Y`, `df1$Y * 0.5`, and `df1$Y * 0.5`.

Then, I would proceed to the next `State`.  The end result should be:

```
df2 <- data.frame(State=c("AL", "AL","AL","AK","AK","AK"), 
                      X=c(1,0,2,3,2,4), y=c(2,1,1,4,2,2))
```

Does anyone know how i might approach this?  I have no idea where to even begin...  I can imagine some kind of for loop, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant approach in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base R solution:

```
funcs.X <- list(function(x) x, function(x) x-1, function(x) x+1)
funcs.y <- list(function(y) y, function(y) y*0.5, function(y) y*0.5)

apply.funcs <- function(funcs,x) as.vector(t(sapply(funcs, function(f) f(x))))

d <- data.frame(State = rep(df1$State,each=length(funcs.X)),
                X = apply.funcs(funcs.X, df1$X),
                y = apply.funcs(funcs.y, df1$y)
                )

identical(d,df2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks Marat, I will accept this answer since i like base R

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(df1)[,list(X=c(X, X-1, X+1), y=c(y,y*0.5, y*0.5)) , State]
all.equal(setDF(res), df2, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```